# How to change react tool tip data-tip value in a react table column?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-tooltip

```
         {
            Header: 'KBMA KPIs',
            accessor: 'metricDescription',
            Cell: (row) => {
                console.log(row)
                return <span data-tip={row.value}>{row.value}</span>;
            }
        }
```

For the value its assign always accessor value. I need to change it to another value in the row?